# Can I use Sharp image processing library in React js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image, sharp

I tried to use [Sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/) image processing in my create react app. But it sends an error
[image]

This is my code:

```
import sharp from 'sharp';

const buffer = await sharp(req.file.buffer)
          .resize({ width: 250, height: 250 })
          .extend({
            top: 10,
            bottom: 10,
            left: 10,
            right: 10,
            background:  '#d7d8de'
          })
          .png()
```

**Edit:** I’m using Node.js version 12.18.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[No.](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1605#issuecomment-471599724)

Sharp uses the node.js runtime as well as binary executable code that is installed on the host system. All this means that Sharp does not work in a web browser.

Comment: Is there any similar library for react js? Actually I like Sharp extend option. But this option are absent in many image processing library.

Answer (score 2):

I see that somebody already provided a good answer, but more alternatives can't hurt

For the simple task of resizing an image that I had to do in a service worker for a Chrome V3 extension, after many tries with canvases I found that [image-js](https://github.com/image-js/image-js) easily did the trick.

Here is a snippet for what I did:

```js
import { Image } from 'image-js';

export const downsizeImage = async (
    imageBase64: string
): Promise<string> => {
  const blob = await fetch(imageBase64).then(r => r.blob());
  const buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();

  const image = await Image.load(buffer);

  const resizedImage = image.resize({ width: 200, height: 200 });

  const imgBuffer = resizedImage.toBuffer();

  // convert to base64
  return Buffer.from(imgBuffer)
      .toString('base64');
}
```